# android databinding on android:background attribute using string color code

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a color code stored as string in a data object called `bean` like the following:

```
public class SpaceBean extends BaseObservable {
    private String selectedThemeColor;

    @Nullable
    @Bindable
    public String getSelectedThemeColor() {
        return selectedThemeColor;
    }

    public void setSelectedThemeColor(String selectedThemeColor) {
        this.selectedThemeColor = selectedThemeColor;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.selectedThemeColor);
    }
}
```

I would like to use databinding expression in a linear layout `android:background` attribute like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_space_detail_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/common_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/common_margin"
        android:background="@{bean.selectedThemeColor}"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
        android:visibility="visible">
```

But it fails to compile with error:

> Error:(80, 35) Cannot find the setter for attribute
>   'android:background' with parameter type java.lang.String on
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.

Comment: Post entire bean file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause there is no method like View.setBackground("#f0f")!

## Instead, you could return a Drawable or a ARGB color value in your SpaceBean.getSelectedThemeColor().

e.g :

```
public class SpaceBean extends BaseObservable {
    private String selectedThemeColor;

    @Nullable
    @Bindable
    public Drawable getSelectedThemeColor() {
        return new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(selectedThemeColor));
    }

    public void setSelectedThemeColor(String selectedThemeColor) {
        this.selectedThemeColor = selectedThemeColor;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.selectedThemeColor);
    }
}
```